# how to run video in autoplay when website is loaded?

Tags: html

I wanna run video in autoplay when the website is loaded and without controls are visible on this because I'm using that video in the banner portion.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **autoplay** attribute

```
<video autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Be aware that the autoplay attribute does not work in mobile devices like iPad and iPhone.